# Cucumber still skipped my scenario after running

Tags: typescript, cucumber

I added cucumber to my project and I don't know why my scenario and all steps is skipped.
Please help

> npx cucumber-js --tags @Test

---

1 scenario (1 skipped)
7 steps (7 skipped)

This is my package.json script

```
"scripts": {"test": "npx cucumber-js --tags @Test"},
```

Here cucumber.json file:

```
{
    "default":{
        "formatOptions":{
            "snippetInterface": "async-await"},
        "paths": [
            "src/features/*.feature"],
            "publishQuiet": true,
            "dryRun": true,
            "require":["src/tests/specs/*.ts"],
            "requireModule": ["ts-node/register"]

    }
}
```

Feature File:

```
@Test
Feature: Basic flow
  Scenario: Creating project with one role
    Given A user open Allocator page
    When Create a new project
    Then The project is successfully saved
    When Create a role within the project
    Then The role is successfully saved
    When Assign a person to the role
    Then The peron is successfully assigned`
```

setting.json:

```
{  "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [ "src/tests/specs/cucumber.spec.ts"],
"cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "src/features/*.feature",
"cucumberautocomplete.formatConfOverride": {},
"cucumber.features": [
   
        "src/features/*.feature",
    
    ],
    "cucumber.glue": [
        "src/tests/specs/cucumber.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

I would like to run my test but it is still skipped?

Comment: U have set dryRun = true...

Comment: you are right, I have taken this setup from random project and didn't know the parameters. Thank you so much!